# Loop "identical" function over all columns of dataframe

Tags: r

given a data frame like:

```
df <- data.frame(A.a = c("a","b","c"),
                 A.b = c("a","b","c"),
                 A.c = c("aa","bb","cc"),
                 B.a = c("w","x","y"))
```

I would like to loop the "identical" function over all columns of the dataframe.
So far I've been able to create this function:

```
loop.col.identical <- function(df){
    for i in colnames(df){
        cat(identical(df[[i]], df[[i]]))
    }
}
```

But it just compares each column with themselves outputting TRUE for everything. I would like to identify that cols A.a and A.b are identical, but A.c is different, given that it also should be identical.
Note that this is a small example, my real data has much more columns and rows.

P.d: sorry for the format, but I'm on my phone

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: A df of 3 cols, col 1 col 2 and a third with the logical statement of identity between col 1 and col 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one idea.

First, create a new data frame with two columns showing the column names to compare. Notice that I removed the one with the same names and the same pair of comparison.

```
dat <- expand.grid(x = names(df), y = names(df))
dat <- dat[dat$x != dat$y, ]
dat <- data.frame(t(apply(dat, 1, sort)), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
dat <- dat[!duplicated(dat), ]
names(dat) <- c("x", "y")
```

After that, we can use `mapply` to loop through the combinations and generate the output as follows.

```
dat$Result <- mapply(function(x, y){
  identical(df[[x]], df[[y]])
}, dat$x, dat$y, SIMPLIFY = TRUE)

dat
#      x   y Result
# 2  A.a A.b   TRUE
# 3  A.a A.c  FALSE
# 4  A.a B.a  FALSE
# 7  A.b A.c  FALSE
# 8  A.b B.a  FALSE
# 12 A.c B.a  FALSE
```

**Update**

As mentioned by @thelatemail, the `combn` function makes the first part easy.

```
dat <- data.frame(t(combn(names(df), 2)), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

dat$Result <- mapply(function(x, y){
  identical(df[[x]], df[[y]])
}, dat$X1, dat$X2, SIMPLIFY = TRUE)

dat
#    X1  X2 Result
# 1 A.a A.b   TRUE
# 2 A.a A.c  FALSE
# 3 A.a B.a  FALSE
# 4 A.b A.c  FALSE
# 5 A.b B.a  FALSE
# 6 A.c B.a  FALSE
```

Comment: `combn` will probably make the first part of this a lot simpler `combn(names(df), 2)` for instance or even `combn(df, 2, FUN=function(x) identical(x[[1]], x[[2]]) )` to kick it along further.

Comment: @thelatemail Thanks for your comment about `combn`. Impressive! I have updated my post based on your comment.

Comment: You can do it as a one-liner by passing `combn` a function and simplifying to a data frame: `dplyr::bind_rows(combn(df, 2, function(x) list(v1 = names(x)[1], v2 = names(x)[2], identical = identical(x[[1]], x[[2]])), simplify = FALSE))`

Comment: I created this function with your feedback:
`loop.col.identical<-function(df){
  dat <- data.frame(t(combn(names(df), 2)), 
                    stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  dat$Result <- mapply(function(x, y){
    identical(df[[x]], df[[y]])
  }, dat$X1, dat$X2, SIMPLIFY = TRUE)
  return(dat)
}`

and then filtered the actual repeated columns with:
`consult.df<-function(df,dfcol,q=TRUE){
  for(i in q)
    query.result<-df[ grep(i, dfcol), ]
  return(query.result)
}`

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to do a pair wise match between the various columns in your data frame.

```
expand.grid(x=colnames(df), y=colnames(df)) %>% 
  mutate(match = map2_lgl(x,y, ~identical(df[[.x]],df[[.y]]))) %>%
  spread(x,match)
```

Here is the output:

```
    y   A.a   A.b   A.c   B.a
1 A.a  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
2 A.b  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
3 A.c FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
4 B.a FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

Depending upon your need you can ignore the last `spread` operation.

Comment: Base R equivalent for this output is `outer(df, df, FUN=Vectorize(identical))`

Comment: This is useful if I wanted to convert boolean to numeric, and then create a dendrogram passing this output as a distance matrix, this was actually my first approach to the problem, using "stringdist", but it crashed with large datasets. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: This one actually helped a lot when comparing columns from different dataframes